# Creating a proper HTML 404 status error response network packet using a raw socket

Tags: html, http-status-codes

I want to construct a proper HTML error message using a raw TCP socket. Right now I simply send

`HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found`

An attached browser (Firefox) with developer tools turned on does usually display HTTP GET response errors nicely (in red at the right of the developer network statistics console). When I send my text in response to a failed HTML GET request, nothing is displayed in the developer tools. I suspect, I need to add some more data, probably a bunch of headers, to the response, so browsers recognize and display the error in their diagnose/statistics tools?

Note: I saw that most webservers attach a nicely formatted HTML body to their error responses, containing the message as HTML formatted text along with some server infos which display in the browser window. This is not what I am after. I am perfectly fine with the browser displaying a blank page, but I want to format the HTML status responses properly, so the browser diagnostics tools do display a meaningful error like they do with any other failed HTML request.

What do I need to send back to the client to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I struggle with your purpose and there are some missing information, about your used tech stack. Therefore I will answer in a more generic way and hopefully add something useful to your goal, so handle my advice with care.

### Status code && reason phrase

> The Status-Code is intended for use by automata and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human user.
>
> [W3.org - 6.1.1 Status Code and Reason Phrase](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) +  [RFC 7230 - 3.1.2. Status Line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)

See and follow the intended goal of the reason phrase! Yes, in theory, you might adjust the phrase and add more "textual" information to a response. Depending on your chosen backend stack, you might have success and the chosen developer tool will recognize your reason phrase.

### HTTP/2

> HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.
>
> [RFC 7540 - 8.1.2.4 Response Pseudo-Header Fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.4)

Your approach is not suitable for *http/2* because of a slightly different approach.

These are RFC specifications. Developer tools are vendor-specific and might have their own behavior to create the *best* response messages.